# iOS : Resizing subview by removing a subview

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

- I have a view which contains 3 `subivews` called `view A`, `view B`, `view C`.
- When I remove a subview means I need to set margin automatically to adjust.
- When I remove `view A` means, remaining `views` have to move up automatically.

**Note:** Not in `autolayout`. Please tell how its possible in `automask`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work automatically, you need to program a bit, you can try the following code to achieve this,

```
//Adding Delete Tap Gesture
-(void)addGestureToSubViews{
    for(UIView *view in parent.subviews){
        UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(deleteAction:)];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    }
}


-(IBAction)deleteAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    UIView *view=sender.view;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        CGRect rect=view.frame;
        rect.origin.x=view.superview.frame.size.width;
        view.frame=rect;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self reArrangeSuperView:view.superview withDeletedViewFrame:view.frame];
        [view removeFromSuperview];

    }];

}

-(void)reArrangeSuperView:(UIView *)superView withDeletedViewFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    for(UIView *view in superView.subviews){
        CGRect rect=view.frame;

        if(rect.origin.y>frame.origin.y){
            rect.origin.y=frame.origin.y;
        }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
            view.frame=rect;
        }];

    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: When i remove view A, its removes view B also.. Beacuse view B height is too long..

Comment: You need to do some modification for this `if(rect.origin.y>frame.origin.y)` according to your need..

Answer (score 0):

For that in the Attribute inspector you have to hide the view and for which view you want push up you should set the -contentoffset property of your view.